# How can I export a DAE file with a non-rest pose?

Tags: export, pose-mode, dae

I am fairly new to Blender and wanted to export a DAE file with a new pose for access to color textures when 3D printing. However, when I export the DAE file, it will always export as a t-pose.

I've tried setting the new pose as the rest pose through the object mode menu but that didn't work. I've also attempted to use the armature modifier though I can't locate it.

I should also note that the model isn't one I made- it comes from a video game.

If anyone would like to help directly, I would be willing to provide the original files if need be. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Select Apply Modifiers in the [Collada export settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/collada.html).